# Use a created object in servlet in JSP/forward object from servlet to JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

As the title says, I am trying to use the same object created in the servlet in my JSP. The object is a model (called "customer" which holds the values/data. I am setting the values in the servlet and getting/printing them in my JSP.

I tried creating a new object in the JSP, but the value becomes null.

At the moment, the variables and the get-methods in the customer class are static. This works, but I don't want them static.
In order to to that, I have to fetch the existing object in my servlet and re-use it in my JSP.

Before anyone says that I should read up, trust me, I have. I just don't understand it properly and I want someone to help me. Please.

This is as far as I have come:

Servlet:

```
String firstName = request.getParameter("förnamn");
Customer control = new Customer ();
control.setFirstName(firstName);
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("förnamn", firstName);

   request.setAttribute("control", control);
        RequestDispatcher view =     request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
```

This is the customer class:

```
private static String firstName;
public static String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public static void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    Customer.firstName = firstName;
}
```

This is my JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Your information in JSP Format:</title>
 <%@ page import="Abdi.Customer" %>
 <%HttpSessionListenerTest http = new HttpSessionListenerTest();%>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li><p><b>Last Name:</b>
 <%= Customer.getFirstName() // i want to print it, without using  static methods%>
</p></li>


 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your Customer class. You've made all the instance variables private static and to access them public static methods. In your case, there will be only one firstName variable no matter how many customer objects you create using new Customer(). Static means one per class definition

Make your variables in Customer class as private and have public setters/getters to mutate the state. Once you've done that you can simply add them as attributes in your servlet in request/session/application scope, forward to a JSP and access them with Expresssion Language(EL) or JSTL. Stop Using scriptlets, they're so 90's.

In Your Servlet,

```
String firstName = request.getParameter("förnamn");
Customer customer = new Customer ();
customer.setFirstName(firstName);
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("customer", customer);
```

--- forward to JSP ----

In Your JSP, just use EL

```
${customer.firstName}
```

In general, `${yourAttributeName.yourPropertyNameFromPOJO}`

Note that I've not mentioned scope of my fName attribute. It will search will all valid scopes starting with Page -> Request -> Session -> Application

If using $ is not resolving these values, then EL is turned off. You can enable it with isELIgnored attribute in your page directive like this

```
<%@ page language="java" isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Comment: I followed your specification and it worked successfully. I checked the assigment again, and I missed that i have to use some form of javabean to access the form data... :/

Comment: Not necessarily u don't have to create a java bean just to access ur form data.. if you're just trying to access the request parameters submitted to ur servlet via some form, then they're available with param in EL with this ${param.urFormParameter}